# Applying Function To Each Member Of A Destructing Assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a way to reduce the minified (by the Closure Compiler with ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS) size of my code. To do this, I am looking for a way to apply a function to each member of a destruction assignment. Browser compatibility is not a concern just so long as Closure understands it. The following is a condensed snippet from my current working code.

```
(function(window){
  "use strict";
  const {"Function": Function, "Array": Array} = window;
  // bindInToBindable(Method)(Instance)(...) = Method.call(Instance, ...)
  const bindInToBindable = Function["prototype"]["bind"]["bind"](Function["prototype"]["bind"]);
  // bindInToCallable(Method)(Instance, ...) = Method.call(Instance, ...)
  const bindInToCallable=bindInToBindable(Function["prototype"]["bind"],Function["prototype"]["call"]);

  const ArrayPrototype = Array["prototype"];
  const CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_POP    =bindInToCallable(ArrayPrototype["POP"])
  const CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_PUSH   =bindInToCallable(ArrayPrototype["PUSH"]);
  const CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_SHIFT  =bindInToCallable(ArrayPrototype["SHIFT"])
  const CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_UNSHIFT=bindInToCallable(ArrayPrototype["UNSHIFT"]);
  // The rest of my code...
})(typeof global==="undefined" ? self : global);
```

[External Link](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540language_out%2520ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A(function(window)%257B%250A%2520%2520%2522use%2520strict%2522%253B%250A%2520%2520const%2520%257B%2522Function%2522%253A%2520Function%252C%2520%2522Array%2522%253A%2520Array%257D%2520%253D%2520window%253B%250A%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520bindInToBindable(Method)(Instance)(...)%2520%253D%2520Method.call(Instance%252C%2520...)%250A%2520%2520const%2520bindInToBindable%2520%253D%2520Function%255B%2522prototype%2522%255D%255B%2522bind%2522%255D%255B%2522bind%2522%255D(Function%255B%2522prototype%2522%255D%255B%2522bind%2522%255D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520bindInToCallable(Method)(Instance%252C%2520...)%2520%253D%2520Method.call(Instance%252C%2520...)%250A%2520%2520const%2520bindInToCallable%253DbindInToBindable(Function%255B%2522prototype%2522%255D%255B%2522bind%2522%255D%252CFunction%255B%2522prototype%2522%255D%255B%2522call%2522%255D)%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520const%2520ArrayPrototype%2520%253D%2520Array%255B%2522prototype%2522%255D%253B%250A%2520%2520const%2520CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_POP%2520%2520%2520%2520%253DbindInToCallable(ArrayPrototype%255B%2522POP%2522%255D)%250A%2520%2520const%2520CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_PUSH%2520%2520%2520%253DbindInToCallable(ArrayPrototype%255B%2522PUSH%2522%255D)%253B%250A%2520%2520const%2520CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_SHIFT%2520%2520%253DbindInToCallable(ArrayPrototype%255B%2522SHIFT%2522%255D)%250A%2520%2520const%2520CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_UNSHIFT%253DbindInToCallable(ArrayPrototype%255B%2522UNSHIFT%2522%255D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520The%2520rest%2520of%2520my%2520code...%250A%257D)(typeof%2520global%253D%253D%253D%2522undefined%2522%2520%253F%2520self%2520%253A%2520global)%253B)

Below is a persuado-code representation of what I am aiming for and have tried so far.

```
(function(window){
  "use strict";
  const {"Function": Function, "Array": Array} = window;
  // bindInToBindable(Method)(Instance)(...) = Method.call(Instance, ...)
  const bindInToBindable = Function["prototype"]["bind"]["bind"](Function["prototype"]["bind"]);
  // bindInToCallable(Method)(Instance, ...) = Method.call(Instance, ...)
  const bindInToCallable=bindInToBindable(Function["prototype"]["bind"],Function["prototype"]["call"]);

  const bindInToCallable({
    "pop": CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_POP,
    "push": CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_PUSH,
    "shift": CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_SHIFT,
    "unshift": CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_UNSHIFT
  }) = Array["prototype"];
  // The rest of my code...
})(typeof global==="undefined" ? self : global);
```

[External Link](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540language_out%2520ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A(function(window)%257B%250A%2520%2520%2522use%2520strict%2522%253B%250A%2520%2520const%2520%257B%2522Function%2522%253A%2520Function%252C%2520%2522Array%2522%253A%2520Array%257D%2520%253D%2520window%253B%250A%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520bindInToBindable(Method)(Instance)(...)%2520%253D%2520Method.call(Instance%252C%2520...)%250A%2520%2520const%2520bindInToBindable%2520%253D%2520Function%255B%2522prototype%2522%255D%255B%2522bind%2522%255D%255B%2522bind%2522%255D(Function%255B%2522prototype%2522%255D%255B%2522bind%2522%255D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520bindInToCallable(Method)(Instance%252C%2520...)%2520%253D%2520Method.call(Instance%252C%2520...)%250A%2520%2520const%2520bindInToCallable%253DbindInToBindable(Function%255B%2522prototype%2522%255D%255B%2522bind%2522%255D%252CFunction%255B%2522prototype%2522%255D%255B%2522call%2522%255D)%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520const%2520bindInToCallable(%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522pop%2522%253A%2520CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_POP%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522push%2522%253A%2520CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_PUSH%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522shift%2522%253A%2520CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_SHIFT%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2522unshift%2522%253A%2520CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_UNSHIFT%250A%2520%2520%257D)%2520%253D%2520Array%255B%2522prototype%2522%255D%253B%250A%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520The%2520rest%2520of%2520my%2520code...%250A%257D)(typeof%2520global%253D%253D%253D%2522undefined%2522%2520%253F%2520self%2520%253A%2520global)%253B)

So, is there a standards-compliant way to apply a function to each member of a destructing assignment? And/Or are there any alternatives that would make the code shorter?

P.S. The above code snippets are only a tiny portion of my real code. In my real code, there are hundreds of declarations, making this reduction in size quite practical.

Comment: @Downvoter Why the downvote? I would think this would be an appropriate question as this question is about size optimization of already working code.

Comment: Is there any way you can modify `bindInToCallable`? Also, why aren't you using dot notation?

Comment: @lolzerywowzery _"however it does not appear to work at all"_ nuff said.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But they already have a working snippet and just want to reduce its size (or this better suited for SO)?

Comment: @AndrewLi Usage of dot notation does not matter. The "size" being compared is not the size of the source code, but rather the size of the minified code.

Comment: @AndrewLi _"or this better suited for SO"_ I dunno, doubt so. _"Code not yet written"_ might apply here anyways.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thank you for pointing out that problem. I have fixed the wording of my description.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The code has been written. Rather the above code snippets are only a tiny portion of my real code. In my real code, there are hundreds of declarations, making this reduction in size quite practical. If you really want I could post a link to the whole thing for you.

Comment: @lolzerywowzery Can we assume you want every single method of the prototype bound?

Comment: @lolzerywowzery _"Rather the above code snippets are only a tiny portion of my real code"_ Lacking concrete context?

Comment: @AndrewLi Yes, I do have every method of the prototype bound. The above code snippet is very condensed and much has been clipped out for simplicity.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is not lacking concrete context. I could explain to you all day the entire project I am working on, but any other code than the stuff above is nonessential to the question being asked here.

Comment: @lolzerywowzery Does it matter if you have `{}` or `Object.create(null)`? You're not going to touch anything other than the bound methods on the returned object right, so there's no difference.

Comment: @AndrewLi You can call me irrational, and I probably am, but I am a javascript programmer with object-oriented-programming-phobia. That includes `{}`, `Object.create(null)`, or non-numerical property access. That's why I am bounding these properties: so that I may access these objects in a function-oriented manner because OOP simply gives me the heebie-jeebies.

Comment: Code Review requires more context than you have given, [please read our meta post about this subject](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3652). Meta is where the community decides the guidelines for what is on-topic for our site.  also please refrain from extended conversation in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating another function which binds the methods of a prototype all at once and returns an object with the bound methods which you can destructure:

```
const bindPrototype = prototype => 
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype)
    .filter(name => typeof prototype[name] === 'function' && name !== 'constructor') //Don't mess with constructors
    .reduce((bound, currName) => {
      bound[currName] = bindInToCallable(prototype[currName]);
      return bound;
    }, {});
```

This takes all the property names of the prototype, filters out the non-methods and constructors, then reduces the array of methods down into an object of all bound methods. Then, you can call it as and destructure/rebind:

```
const {
  pop: CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_POP,
  …
} = bindPrototype(Array.prototype);
```

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant. It fulfills every aspect of the question I asked, so it would be a crime to not mark it as the correct answer. However, I have a strict no-object-oriented coding policy whereby I never ever use the evils of non-numerical property access, or objects like {} or Object.create(null) except where required by bultin native methods. Instead I only use numerical `[]` and bind native methods such as CALL_ARRAY_PROTOTYPE_PUSH(myArray,value) instead of calling myArray.push (value). Nevertheless, I do applaud you with extravagant praise for this unique and original solution.

Comment: @lolzerywowzery Thanks! I didn't expect it to be faster at all but it is a bit shorter. Also just curious why you've commented the same comment a few times now (it sends me a notification since I'm in the app).

Comment: Sorry, I have a bad habit of posting a comment, going back to reread it, and realizing there was something I could improve about the wording.

Comment: @lolzerywowzery No problem, that's what I suspected. Cheers!